# Making Xcode complain about a missing parameter

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I am designing a new application by modernizing code I wrote in the past. This old code uses the class/delegate model and I am trying to transform them to use blocks as callbacks, not the delegate stuff.

What I do is to create a property like

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onTouch)(NSInteger index);
```

That would pass to the object using that class a block where code can be inserted and in this case executed on touch.

But my problem is this. When you use delegates and you have a method on the delegate protocol, Xcode will warn if you use that class and forget to implement the delegate protocols. Is that a way to do that with blocks? Or in other words: is there a way to make Xcode complain if a callback block is not defined by the caller?

I mean this would be the correct:

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
obj.onTouch = ^(NSInteger *index){ //call back code to be executed };
```

This would be OK too

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
obj.onTouch = nil;
```

but this would generate a message

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
// no callback block defined.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enforce setting a certain parameter, I would include it in the initializer.

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithBlock:^(NSInteger *index) { /* code*/ }];
```

Then, in `MyClass`:

```
- (id)init {
  // This will result in a runtime error if you use the wrong initializer.
  NSAssert(NO, @"Use initWithBlock instead.");
}

- (id)initWithBlock(initWithBlock:^(NSInteger *)block) {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.onTouch = block;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Also note, attempting to execute a `NULL` block results in a crash, so make sure to do:

```
if (self.onTouch) { self.onTouch(); }
```

Wherever you run the block.

Answer (score 1):

First, I strongly recommend [defining types to represent your blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1) - makes them a lot easier to work with, especially if you need to refactor the parameters.

You can't write code that distinguishes between "I set this property to nil" or "the runtime initialized this property to nil", at least not without some crazy runtime code to check the stack. Only option I can think of would be to use the [null object pattern](http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jwalker/nullObjPattern/). Before I elaborate, bear in mind that I haven't actually tried to test this, but it should work. Define a block that means 'has no value' and set your property to point to that block on init. Then you can compare to that `NullBlock` at runtime to identify if someone explicitly set the property to nil (because it would be nil at that point) or gave it a real non-nil value.

Alternatively, if you don't mind manually writing your set accessors, you could have a BOOL that tracks if someone set the property explicitly. Then when you call the block just check if someone actually set the value or not.

```
@synthesize onTouchBlock=_onTouchBlock;
MyBlock _onTouchBlock;
BOOL _onTouchBlockWasSet;

- (void)setOnTouchBlock:(MyBlock)block {
 _onTouchBlockWasSet = YES;
 _onTouchBlock = block;
}
```

I would not recommend passing the value in the initializer because that makes it tied to the creation of that object type. If you wanted to change the block in code based on some condition, you'd be back to square one. Also, it prevents you from using storyboards which create that object.